# Hosting WCF on IIS - EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

After implemeting a WCF service, hosting it on the IIS Server, it returned with the below error.

> **EndpointNotFoundException** was unhandled by user code There was no
>   endpoint listening at XXXXX that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See
>   InnerException, if present, for more details.

That service is identically has the same implementation and configuration of 5 running services with no errors.

when I tried to figure out what is going on the IIS server, the below screenshot.
[image]

So it seems that this specific service has no detected Contract. although I'm using the same configuration as below.

```
      <service name="XX.XX.Provisioning.EldaftarManagementService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProvisioningServiceBinding" bindingNamespace="http://XX.XX.com/XX/" contract="XX.XX.Provisioning.Eldaftar.IEldaftarManagementService" />
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProvisioningBasicBinding" bindingNamespace="http://XX.XX.com/provisioning/" contract="XX.XX.Provisioning.Eldaftar.IEldaftarManagementService" />
      </service>
<service name="XX.XX.Provisioning.Common.UserManagement.UserManagementService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProvisioningServiceBinding" bindingNamespace="http://XX.XX.com/XX/" contract="XX.XX.Provisioning.Common.UserManagement.IUserManagementService" />
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProvisioningBasicBinding" bindingNamespace="http://XX.XX.com/provisioning/" contract="XX.XX.Provisioning.Common.UserManagement.IUserManagementService" />
      </service>
```

Kindly noted that when accessing the service.svc url it replies normally and the wsdl is shown. So that means it's hosted fine on the IIS.

Do I miss something?

Update:

Client config.

```
 <endpoint address="https://XXX/EldaftarManagementService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ProvisioningClientBehaviour" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProvisioningServiceBinding" contract="EldaftarManagementService.IEldaftarManagementService" />
 <endpoint address="https://XXX/UserManagement.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ProvisioningClientBehaviour" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProvisioningServiceBinding" contract="UserManagementService.IUserManagementService" />
```

Comment: Try to refresh your reference. There might have been a change at the service that's not handled in your client.

Comment: It seems that the problem is in the client side. It would be useful to post the config files values in the client side in order to check if they match with the ones on the server.

Comment: Check the namespace of the contract.  Is it XX.XX.Provisioning.Eldaftar?

Comment: check that your contract interface matches the client.

Comment: In the client, take a look at Service References\EldaftarManagementService\reference.cs IEldaftarManagementServiceCallBack. Is it identical to IEldaftarManagementService on the service?

Comment: @mrtig - where is that Callback method?

Comment: should be in your service "Reference.cs" file, if you "show all files" in your solution explorer. -I assumed you've got the source code of the client.

Comment: @mrtig - they are identical

Comment: Do you have https enabled? `<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>`

Comment: @mrtig - yes its enabled.

Answer (score 0):

i notice sometime after reconfigure my service reference, the client config getting wsdl with server name. then i get EndpointNotFoundException exception.

example :

service reference is : `http://192.168.61.2:1111/Service1.svc`

but in the config endpoint address it show : `http://serverName:1111/Service1.svc`

After i change the config endpoint address with the service reference address , then it resolved. Not sure why but now every time when i reconfigure the endpoint address, i will manually change the config endpoint address to make sure it get the same address.